# How to connect to remote SQL Server using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

First, the config....
-- Running SQL 2012 Developer (default instance MSSQLServer only) on Vista Home Premium
-- SQL/Vista box (HomeOfficePC) connects to home router via wireless
-- HomeOfficePC has a fixed ip assigned on the router
-- HomeOfficePC is running (on auto) SQL engine(tcp 1433), ReportServer (tcp 80), Analysis Svcs
-- HomeOfficePC is not running (on manual) Browser or Agent
-- HomeOfficePC firewall has TCP 1433, TCP 80 and UDP 1434 ports open for inbound
-- HomeOfficePC firewall TCP 1433 is pointed to sqlservr.exe
-- HomeOfficePC firewall UDP 1434 is open, but not pointed.
-- Router (2Wire from AT&T) is pinholed to forward TCP 1433 to HomeOfficePC fixed ip
-- Router is pinholed to forward UDP 1434 to HomeOfficePC fixed ip
-- Router is pinholed to forward TCP 80 to HomeOfficePC fixed ip

Second, the successes....
-- I can remotely connect+qry to HomeOffice\MSSQLSERVER via SSMS (shared mem) from laptop while at home
-- I can remotely connect+qry to HomeOfficePC\MSSQLSERVER via Android Galaxy S2 (my cell phone) SQL client app
-- I can connect to Report Server locally and remotely from any domain

Now, the failures...
-- I cannot remotely connect to HomeOffice\MSSQLSERVER via SSMS from any other remote location (work, Starbucks, etc.) ... And yes, I made sure the SSMS client is running tcp/ip.

So my questions are:
-- Is it syntax? How exactly do i connect to a remote SQL server ip using SSMS?

Comment: You need to connect to an exposed DNS name or IP as the server, not your PC's name on your home network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it would or would not work via Android, but I just had to troubleshoot an issue on our company network.  Here was the issue after installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express:

In addition to configuring the Windows Firewall to allow incoming connections on TCP Port 1433, you will need to start the SQL Server Browser service.  This service can be found on the Start Menu - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 - Configuration Tools - SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Once there, click SQL Server Services on the left, then SQL Server Browser on the right.  This is disabled by default.

1. Right click SQL Server Browser and choose Properties
2. Click the Service Tab
3. For property Start Mode, choose Automatic
4. Click Apply
5. Click the Log On tab
6. Choose the appropriate account for log on (I used built in service account)
7. Click Apply
8. Click Start
9. Click OK

This solved my problem on Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Each SQL Server instance uses a different port on TCP/IP. If you are using the standard Windows Firewall, each of them must be unblocked for private and/or public networks, depending on your needs.
Check your firewall rules for the port used by the MSSQLSERVER instance. Possibly it is unblocked only for private networks.

Comment: Ty for the replies. For clarification, yes, port 1433 is open for all networks. Port 80 is also open. I'm able to remotely access Reports url. Also, my remote connect attempts via Android SQL client (successful), via BIDS deploy from laptop-at-Starbucks of some dummy rpts to ReportServer (port 80) and thus into ReportServer db (successful), SSMS at work (unsuccessful), SSMS on laptop-at-Starbucks (unsuccessful) have been by using tcp to port 1433 on my router's public ip address. Again, works great via my Android. Can't understand why I can't remote connect via SSMS from work pc or my laptop.